# In socket.io chat app my chat printing twice on that side from where i am typing

Tags: socket.io

from sending side emiting side 
,now when i send my text from emit side it print it twice on this side 
but print only once on other side

```
send.addEventListener('click',(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    if(nameUser.value){
        var msgDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var userName = document.createTextNode(nameUser.value+' :: ');
        msgDiv.appendChild(userName);
        var brk = document.createElement('div')
        brk.style.height = '10px';
        msgDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#f87901';
        msgDiv.style.padding = '8px';
        msgDiv.style.width = 'auto';
        msgDiv.style.height = 'auto';
        msgDiv.style.display = 'inline-block';
        msgDiv.style.borderRadius = '20px';
        var msg = document.createTextNode(textBox.value);
        msgDiv.appendChild(msg);
        msgDiv.style.color = 'white';
        boxBody.appendChild(msgDiv); 
        boxBody.appendChild(brk);  

        socket.emit('text',{
            value:textBox.value
        });
        textBox.value = '';
    }
})
```

on other client side receiving, here working fine printing only once but when it work as sender then prints twice again this side and once on other client i don't know what is the problem

```
socket.on('text',data =>{
    msgDiv = document.createElement('div');
    brk = document.createElement('div')
    brk.style.height = '10px';
    msgDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
    msgDiv.style.padding = '8px';
    msgDiv.style.width = 'auto';
    msgDiv.style.height = 'auto';
    msgDiv.style.display = 'inline-block';
    msgDiv.style.borderRadius = '20px';
    msg = document.createTextNode(data.value);
    msgDiv.appendChild(msg);
    boxBody.appendChild(msgDiv); 
    boxBody.appendChild(brk); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that into js. But if I understand correctly you create a `div` on the sending side. That gets appended to the body `boxBody.appendChild(brk);`. That will show the message even if it's not sent successfully.

The solution would be to only emit the message and let it get created through the socket event making sure that the message got emitted correctly.

(Untested Kind-Pseudocode)

```
send.addEventListener('click',(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    if(nameUser.value){    
        socket.emit('text',{
            value:textBox.value
        });
        textBox.value = '';
    }
})
```

You probably should also send a username of some sort, for display purposes.

Please see the example application https://socket.io/demos/chat/
The source is also available at https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat.

Hope this helps.

Have a great one